# SQL SELECT * but with a twist - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, prepared-statement

OK lets say I want to select a number of columns from a database table, but I won't know what those columns are in the method. I could pass them in, but it could be more or less depending on the method calling the database method.

A quick fix would be SELECT *, but I understand that this is bad and can cause more data to be returned than is necessary, and I definitely don't need all the data from that table.

So I am using CodeIgniter and prepared statements to do this, and below is what I have currently (it works, just point that out).

```
function get_pages() {
        $this->db->select('pages.id, pages.title, pages.on_nav, pages.date_added, admin.first_name, admin.last_name')
                 ->from('pages, admin') 
                 ->where('pages.admin_id = admin.id')
                 ->order_by('pages.id', 'ASC');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
```

It's a simple function, but at the moment limited to getting only 'pages'. I want to convert this to work with getting from other tables too. What is the best way?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**  In CodeIgniter I have many Controllers. One for 'pages', one for 'products', one for 'news' and on and on. I don't want to create a single database query method in my model for each controller.

Comment: I seem to have missed the actual question. What is it you are having trouble with? How is this related to **codeigniter** or **prepared-statement** s? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I want to select a number of columns from a database table. The function is only for one table at the moment, however I want to be able to select from other tables depending on the method that calls the database get method. I don't want to select everything. 

It's either create one method that does it, or have multiple methods containing similar code. That just seems unnecessary.

Comment: Searching for `pages.*, admin.first_name, admin.last_name`?

Comment: That is essentially selecting all. In CodeIgniter I have many Controllers. One for 'pages', one for 'products', one for 'news' and on and on. I don't want to create a single database query method in my model for each controller is what I guess I should have said at first.

Comment: I'm a little lost too. If each table has a unique SQL query, then somewhere in your code, you will need to create that query. Normally, you have a model correspond to a table, it contains the query and the controller asks as many models as necessary for the information.

If you are saying that you want one model that returns different information based on who called it, that's kind of backwards.

Answer (score 0):

i think the desire to not have 4 methods is misguided.  if you don't have the information in the method, you'll have to pass it in.  so you could either pass in a string with the table you want and switch over that changing the query based on the table name, or pass in all of the necessary parts of the query.  this would include table name, criteria column, criteria, and columns to select.  and you'd need to pass that information in every time you called the function.  neither of those two methods are really going to save you much code, and they're both less readable than a function for each purpose.

Comment: I kinda thought that too, but I wasn't really sure as I've not had to deal with this in the past. I was erring on the side of creating individual methods, but I wasn't sure... Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea with models to put your specific queries to the persistence layer in there. Using a generic catch-all method can be disastrous and hard to test. You should shape your model around the problem you're trying to solve.

This makes it much cleaner and easier to work with. At the same time you must also avoid the common trap of over-sizing models. Each model should follow the SRP. Try and separate concerns so that in your controller, you can easily see state changes.

Does that make sense or am I just rambling...?

Comment: What you are suggesting is not only having a Controller for each section, but a Model also? I can understand why you might do that for larger projects, but this just needs to get stuff from the database. At the moment I have one Database Model. Though I might have interpreted you wrong.

Comment: I could be wrong - and if I am, I hope a more experienced programmer will correct me.

This is really dependent on your problem space. You could implement one controller to one model. That is one way of segregating your app into parts. This makes it more reusable when you want to start a new project. However you need to think of models more like a layer. It's your go-between the persistence layer and the rest of your app.

So based on your problem, I'd say one model to fetch all page data would be okay. However as your site gets larger, you'll notice your model will get pretty big. SRP is key.

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
function get_pages($table_source) {
    $this->db->select($table_source.".id"); // or $this->db->select('id');

// for instance, if one of your $table_source ="users" and there is no 'title' column you can write
    if($table_source!='users') $this->db->select('title');

    $this->db->select('on_nav');
    $this->db->select('date_added');
    $this->db->select('admin.first_name');
    $this->db->select('admin.last_name'); 
    $this->db->join('admin','admin.id = '.$table_source.'.admin_id') 
    $this->db->order_by('pages.id', 'ASC');

    $query = $this->db->get($table_source);

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In your controller:

```
function all_tables_info() {
    $tables = array("pages","users","customers"); 
    $i=0;
    foreach($tables as $table) {
    $data[$i++]=$this->your_Model->get_pages($table);
 }
  //do somthing with $data
}
```